# Contradicting outputs in Xilinx ISim

Tags: vhdl, verilog, fpga

I am facing a strange problem in Xilinx ISE. My simulation window shows different hex values to same variable( contradiction between value window and signal window as can be seen from attached image). Count has value FA shown in value window while the signal window shows 7A which is strange and leads to wrong outputs. According to the code, it should be 7A. I have no clue whats happening. Can anybody help. [image]

P.S. My code is integration of VHDL and Verilog codes.

Comment: That's weird, but we can't really debug without details. Please include your code (including the testbench).

Comment: It's strange. I think you should contact Xilinx directly, as this seems a bug in their ISE

Comment: You've put the cursor on the transition. Could there not be glitches between the 7B and 7A values?

Comment: This is not verifiable. If we cannot reproduce it, we are not able to help you. Are you running the latest version of ISIM? p.s. maybe you should switch to Vivado anyhow.

Comment: I agree, contact support.  Maybe also check the hierarchical path of your counter/signals to be sure it's the expected ones. Maybe compare with other tools if available (or maybe here if needed: https://www.edaplayground.com).

Comment: I have switched to Vivado and there is no issue with same piece of code.